# Angular document creator page breakpoints

Tags: html, css, angular, pdf, document

I have an Agnular app which should function as a document (invoices etc...) creator.
The whole idea is that I have a fix header and a footer to work with.

I use CSS grid to make the basic layout.

```
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'top' 'data' 'foot';
```

My problem is this: Lets say they want a table in the **'data'** section, which is i dont know how many rows long, and if it's too long, that it can't fit between the header and the footer, I have currently no way to know that.

I can create page breaks like this:

```
  .break {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
```

But I want to use something like this dynamically, so if any content is too large for the data area, it gets broken into pages.

There isnt a thing like I have to show 50 items of a specific class. It should be fully dynamic, tables, texts, bigger texts, literally anything with unknown sizes

Any idea how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about pagination.

Pagination can be either client side or server side.

Client side pagination is much simpler. Server side pagination requires a backend API that can handle pagination.

Angular libraries such as Angular material often come with components to assist with pagination such as https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

Here's how client side pagination works:

1. make an HTTP request to server for list of ALL items - e.g. GET /items
2. get the items array and organise it into a multidimensional array. e.g. [200 items] becomes [[50 items], [50 items], [50 items], [50 items]]
3. use *ngFor to list the first 50 items
4. when the user clicks next page, use *ngFor to list the second 50 items
5. and so on

Here's how server side pagination works:

1. make an HTTP request to server for list of items with offset and limit params - e.g. GET /items?offset=0&limit=50

NB: This will return items OFFSET to OFFSET+LIMIT-1 - here, items 0 to 49 (the first 50 items)

2. Use *ngFor to list the items the server sent you
3. When the user clicks next, make another HTTP request for the next 50 items - e.g. /items?offset=50&limit=50 (items 50 to 99)
4. Use *ngFor to list the items the server sent you
5. and so on

Client side pagination is easier to implement because it does not depend on the server API call supporting offset and limit params.
Client side pagination performs poorly where the list contains too many items (e.g. 10,000). Client side pagination looks faster because only one HTTP request is made up front so there is no HTTP delay when loading the next items.

Server side pagination is better for large lists BUT requires someone on your backend team to add support for offset and limit params to the API. If they can't then this is not an option.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think my problem is more complicated, because there isnt a thing like I have to show 50 items of a specific class. It should be fully dynamic, tables, texts, bigger texts, literally anything with unknown sizes.

Comment: yes I know - and if I wrote an answer accommodating all the ins and outs of pagination it would not be an answer, it would be a book - this answer is meant to give you a general understanding so that you can tailor it to your specific situation, obviously you can introduce variables to dynamically change 50 to 25, you can *ngFor over <tr> rows, etc